# AngularUI Router - scroll to element on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have searched on StackOverflow for the last five hours and none of the related answers quite solve my problem. I have an UI-Router state that loads a long list of messages generated from a custom directive. This page is linked too in many places pointing to a different message. I want to scroll to the currently selected message.

I can get this to work using $anchorScroll if I surround the call with a $timeout. `$timeout(function(){$anchorScroll()};)` but if the $timeout is not there a call to $anchorScroll does nothing since the View has not completely loaded.

Here is most of the relevant code.

```
<message id='message{{message.id}}'
   ng-repeat='message in messages'
   message='message'
   ng-class="{'current':current == 'message{{message.id}}'}" >
</message>
```

In the controller I set current to `$scope.current = $location.hash()`. This all works.

If I load the page like `#/messages#message100` directly the page will correctly scroll.  However, if from a different view I use the a link such as this:

```
<button ui-sref="message-state({'#':'message{{message.id}}'})>
  Go To Message {{message.id}}
</button>
```

The page will not automatically scroll to the correct anchor since the message list has not been made yet. But by putting the call to $anchorScroll() in a $timeout I can make the page scroll.

I don't like using $timeout for this purpose.  I know I am not supposed to manipulate the DOM in a controller like this.

I have tried registering the call to $anchorScroll() with many of the $stateProvider events such as:

```
$state.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
  $anchorScroll();
});
```

But even at the time the $viewContentLoaded fires the message list does not exist in the DOM and the page does not scroll.

IWhat is the best way to make the UI-Router scroll based on the $location.hash().

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing a similar situation and after days of try and error, I came up with this.

In ui router add an id parameter to the state on which you want to enable the scroll.

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    params: {
        id: null
    }
})
```

Then in the html use ui-sref

```
<li><a ui-sref="index({id: 'about-us'})"  >About Us</a></li>
```

At last in the app.run module detect the state change using

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
    if ($state.current.name == 'index') {
        if($stateParams.id) {
            $anchorScroll.yOffset = 150;
            $location.hash($stateParams.id);
            $timeout(function(){$anchorScroll()}, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Would do a plunkr if needed.